# Нужны ли указанные запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Программа развивалась более 30 лет(,)с учетом опыта эксплуатации в десятках фирм России и СНГ.

Точность расчета обеспечивается за счет автоматического пересчета свойств продукта и режимов течения на каждом участке, а также детального расчета прямых труб и местных сопротивлений (,)с учетом режима течения в соответствии со справочниками Идельчика, Миллера,и современными методами расчета многофазных течений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, обе запятые не нужны - здесь ведь нет ни перечисления, ни двух простых предложений в составе сложного.
Так что запятые не ставятся. А остальные расставлены верно.

Answer (score 2):

1. Без запятой из первой фразы следует, что "более 30 лет развитие программы шло с учётом...", и возникает вопрос: а по прошествии этих лет с учётом было покончено?
2. Если ту запятую поставить, то смысл изменится и между частями фразы появится нежелательная причинно-следственная связь: якобы "опыт эксплуатации" показывал, что развивать программу нужно было не меньше 30 лет, с учётом этого она так долго равивалась.
3. Чтобы яснее объединить смысл имеющихся здесь двух утверждений (развивалась сколько времени + развивалась с учётом чего), можно изменить так:
   Программа развивалась более 30 лет и учитывала опыт эксплуатации (чего) в десятках фирм России и СНГ.
4. Во второй фразе запятая в том месте не нужна (как и после слова "Миллера" - там нужен пробел), но после "учётом режима течения" я бы поставил тире: без этого восприятию фразы мешает словосочетание "течения в соответствии со справочниками".